# Curl command issue in bash script because of string variable containing quotes

Tags: bash, curl

I am executing curl command inside bash script.

Issue is in curl command I have to pass some variables($summary,$description).
but as these variables are in single quote('), variables are not getting assigned.

FYI: I can't remove single quote and also can't replace with double quotes.

How can I overcome this situation.

Curl Command:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"summary": "$summary",  "description": "$description", "moduleMapAssets": [{"name":"Rates | IRD"},{"name":"CRD | CRD"}]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: "I can't remove single quote and also can't replace with double quotes." -> with that limitation, what you want cannot be done. Variables won't be interpreted inside single quotes. Why do you say you can't remove or change them?

Comment: In curl command  string after -d should be passed in single quote. I tried by removing it and also replacing it with double quote but in this case command through bad request error. so looking for workaround.

Comment: "In curl command string after -d should be passed in single quote." No, sir.

Comment: Use a tool like `jq` to generate JSON like this; it takes care of making sure the contents of `summary` and `description` get escaped properly when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and must) use double-quotes, you just need to escape the double-quotes that are part of the string:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"summary\": \"$summary\",  \"description\": \"$description\", \"moduleMapAssets\": [{\"name\":\"Rates | IRD\"},{\"name\":\"CRD | CRD\"}]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

As @MikeHolt pointed out in a comment, it's also possible to mix quoting styles within a single string, so you could switch back and forth between single-quoted sections that include literal double-quotes, and double-quoted sections that include variable references:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"summary": "'"$summary"'",  "description": "'"$description"'", "moduleMapAssets": [{"name":"Rates | IRD"},{"name":"CRD | CRD"}]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

To explain that in a little more detail: `... '{"summary": "'"$summary"'", "description"...'` is parsed as the single-quoted section `'{"summary": "'` (within which the double-quotes are literal), followed immediately by the double-quoted section `"$summary"` (within which the variable gets expanded), followed immediately by another single-quoted section `'", "description"...'` etc. Since there are no spaces between these sections, they're treated as one long argument to `curl`.

BTW, if any of your variables can contain double-quotes or backslashes themselves, things get *much* more complicated. If something like this is a possibility, you should be using something like `jq` to create the string. Something like this:

```
jsonstring=$(jq -n --arg summary "$summary" --arg description "$description" '{
    summary: $summary,
    description: $description,
    moduleMapAssets: [{name: "Rates | IRD"}, {name: "CRD | CRD"}]
    }' )
curl -X POST -d "$jsonstring" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that bash will happily concatenate strings with different quoting styles, as long as you don't have any whitespace in between, e.g., `'foo'"bar"` is equivalent to `"foobar"`. It might ease the burden of having to escape every single `"`.

Comment: @MikeHolt Good point; see update.

Answer (score -3):

try use with backslash on sigle-quotes

```
curl -X POST -d \'{"summary": "$summary",  "description": "$description", "moduleMapAssets": [{"name":"Rates | IRD"},{"name":"CRD | CRD"}]}\' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: This is wrong. The shell will do word-splitting on this and turn it into multiple args.

Comment: Thanks but its not working either